# How to create documentation with devtools while building a package?

Tags: r, devtools

Well, I want to create a documentation in my package project but I get this error:

```
library(devtools)
> devtools::document()
Updating varbinq documentation
Loading varbinq
Error: contains a blank line
```

why when I have no blank line in my function! It looks like this:

```
#' function which do something
#'
#' @param x a value of something
#' @return a value of something2
#' @examples
#' f(2)
f <- function(x){
  x+2
}
```

maybe it's because of others functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen when there's a blank line in the package DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: yeah I have already found it and wanted to write the answer, but ya were faster. :) thx!